# How to compare the type using C# Generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a program which needs to do something based on two different types A and B which are not related ?
How can I do so ? I cannot inherit A and/or B from a common interface.

```
 public class Proxy<T>
 {
        public T GetProxy()
     {
         if (typeof(T) is A)
             // Do something;
         else if (typeof(T) is B)
            // Do something else;                  
    }
}
```

I am making calls as below, but typeof(T) doesnot equals A or B, but to System.RuntimeType.

```
var proxyA = Proxy<A>.GetProxy();
var proxyB = Proxy<B>.GetProxy();
```

Comment: You're using generics wrong.

Comment: If you're using typeof or GetType, you probably shouldn't be using generics.

Comment: It looks like you should have an `IProxy<T>` and different implementations for `A` and `B`.

Comment: Instead of using `is`, just do `typeof(T) == typeof(A)`

Comment: What is your use-case for this? What you seem to be doing doesn't make sense to use Generics.

Answer (score 9):

You can test the types like this:

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
     public T GetProxy()
     {
         if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
             // Do something;
         else if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
            // Do something else;                  
    }
}
```

Or possibly like this:

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
     public T GetProxy()
     {
         if (typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
             // Do something;
         else if (typeof(B).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            // Do something else;                  
    }
}
```

However, generics aren't really supposed to be used this way. If you find yourself doing completely different things for two completely different types, this probably isn't the best use of generics.

Comment: Yep. If you're testing types in generic code, it ain't generic. Why bother?

Comment: 1 for IsAssignableFrom

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to fulfill your requirement

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
    public T GetProxy()
 {
     if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
         // Do something;
     else if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
        // Do something else;                  
}
}
```